# JavaScript bind vs anonymous function

Tags: javascript, node.js, anonymous-function

[This code](https://github.com/buunguyen/mongoose-deep-populate/blob/master/test/plugin.js#L514) from mongoose-deep-populate

```
  async.parallel([
  User.create.bind(User, {_id: 1, manager: 2, mainPage: 1}),
  Comment.create.bind(Comment, {_id: 3, user: 1}),
  ...
], cb)
```

uses `Function.prototype.bind` to ensure that `this` is bound to the proper object when the callback function `User.create` is executed in a different context. Is this equivalent to

```
async.parallel([
    function() { User.create({_id: 1, manager: 2, mainPage: 1}) }, 
    function() { Comment.create({_id: 3, user: 1}) },
], cb)
```

?

If so, in what situation is `bind` a more preferable syntax compared to using an anonymous function?

Comment: That's going to be a matter of opinion, and influenced by the actual situation at hand.

Comment: _Is this equivalent?_ Yes, in this case, the anonymous functions are equivalent to the use of `.bind()`

Comment: The term "lambda" is generally not used for JS anonymous functions.

Comment: You would need to add `return` statements in your anonymous functions for them to be closer to equivalent. There can be other subtle differences, but probably won't matter given your example.

Comment: Note: These aren't entirely equivalent. `async.parallel()` provides a callback to each function as an argument. With `.bind()`, the callback will automatically be passed on. With anonymous functions, the equivalent would be `function (...args) { User.create({ /* ... */ }, ...args); }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two are quite different in a way that isn't clear in your example because you are using constant values, but consider the following:

```
function mul(num, times) {
    return num * times;
}

function fn1() {
    let num = 3;

    let cb = function(times) {
        return mul(num, times);
    }

    num = 5;
    console.log(`num is now: ${ num }`);

    return cb;
}

function fn2() {
    let num = 3;

    let cb = mul.bind(null, num);

    num = 5;
    console.log(`num is now: ${ num }`);

    return cb;
}
```

When you run the two you'll get different results:

```
let a1 = fn1()(5); // a1 === 25
let a2 = fn2()(5); // s2 === 15
```

The difference between the two is that when using `bind` you bind the current values to the function (as parameters) while when using an anonymous function the used values will be the ones that exist when the function is invoked.

In some scenarios you might even face an `undefined` when the function is executed:

```
var a = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
function fn(value, index) {
    console.log(value, index);
}

// doesn't work as i is undefined when the function is invoked
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        fn(a[i], i);
    }, 45);
}

// works because the value of i and the value of a[i] are bound
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(fn.bind(null, a[i], i), 45);
}
```

(the example with the anonymous function will work if you use `let` instead of `var`)

The same happens when you want to pass a value which is a result of calling another function:

```
let counter = {
    _current: 0,
    get: function() {
        return this._current++;
    }
}

let map = {
    _items: Object.create(null),
    set: function(key, value, index) {
        this._items[key] = {
            index: index,
            value: value
        }
    }
}

// using anonymous functions the index in most cases won't reflect the real order
setTimeout(function() {
    map.set("one", 1, counter.get());
}, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500) + 100);
setTimeout(function() {
    map.set("two", 2, counter.get());
}, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500) + 100);
setTimeout(function() {
    map.set("three", 3, counter.get());
}, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500) + 100);

// using bind, the index will always be correct
setTimeout(map.set.bind(map, "one", 1, counter.get()), Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500) + 100);
setTimeout(map.set.bind(map, "two", 2, counter.get()), Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500) + 100);
setTimeout(map.set.bind(map, "three", 3, counter.get()), Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500) + 100);
```

The reason it works differently is that when binding the `counter.get()` gets evaluated before the `bind` function is invoked so the correct return value is bound.
When using an anonymous function the `counter.get()` is evaluated only when the function is executed, and the order of which anonymous function is called isn't known.